# Esperar a que termine los procesos dentro del for antes de seguir en NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose

Dentro de mi controlador tengo una función que se encarga de subir los productos a la base de datos. Como los productos se envian por un array que puede tener uno o mas productos para procesar y posteriormente subir si es que no existe en la base. Si existe ese producto se agrega a el error a err_lines con el indice del producto para mostrar en el front en que linea está el producto existente. Pero como no se como hacer para esperar exactamente a que termine de procesar todos los productos antes de retornar lo esperado.

```
const Base = require('./modules/base');
const Product = require('./modules/product');


module.exports.create = (tag, ccn, products) => {
    let err_lines = [];

    const base = Base.findOne({ tag });
    if (!base) {
        const new_base = new Base({ tag });
        new_base.save().catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    if (products.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            const { id, name, description } = products[i];
            Product.findOne({ ccn })
                .then(result => {
                    if (result) {
                        err_lines[i+1] = 'Este producto ya existe.';
                        console.log(`debugger: 1 - ${err_lines}`);
                    } else {
                        const new_product = new Product({ base: base._id, name, description });
                        new_product.save().catch(error => console.log(error));
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
            console.log(`debugger: 2 - ${err_lines}`);
        }
    }

    console.log(`debugger: 3 - ${err_lines}`);

    // debugger: 2 - 
    // debugger: 3 - 
    // debugger: 1 - ,Este producto ya existe.
    // if (err_lines.length > 0) {
    //     return { message: 'Productos subidos correctamente.' }
    // } else {
    //     return { err_lines, message: 'Productos subidos correctamente.' }
    // }
};
```

Comment: En "Product.findOne({ ccn })", ¿de donde sale "ccn"?

Comment: Ese se recibe como parametro. Lo había quitado porque parece relebante para esta publicación. Pero ya actualice la publicación.

Comment: En realidad, quería saber de donde salía porque quizás podías generar las promesas en tu for (generando un array de promesas), y luego resolverlas con un Promise.all().
Pero en realidad, tu ccn no cambia. Por ende, adentro del for, no tiene sentido llamar a la promesa. Ahí te explico mejor en la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código que mandaste, ccn no se modifica en cada iteración del for.

Por ende, entiendo que `Product.findOne({ ccn })` siempre te va a devolver lo mismo.
Esto no está bueno (estás abriendo varias consultas para traer siempre el mismo resultado).
Si esto es así (si siempre traés el mismo producto), te recomiendo sacar el `Product.findOne({ccn})` afuera del for. Luego, resolver tu for de forma más simple adentro del "then" de esa promesa.

Si esto no es así (si en realidad, necesitás hacer algo así como `Product.findOne({id:id})` (o sea, que tu findOne busque un producto por algún parámetro que sí varíe en el bucle), podrías resolverlo así:

```
const prom = [];
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            const { id, name, description } = products[i];
            prom.push(Product.findOne({id:id});
        }
    Promise.all(prom).then(arrResult=>{
        // acá resolvé lo que necesites. Se va a ejecutar una vez que se hayan cumplido todas las promesas
    });
    }
```

Sin embargo, tampoco es lo mejor (ya que estás haciendo muchas llamadas a la base de datos en un for, y eso tiene un costo). Lo ideal sería (para este caso) ir a una solución del tipo find.

```
let arrIds = [];
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    const { id, name, description } = products[i];
    arrIds.push(id);
}
Product.find({
    'id': { $in: arrIds}
}).then(result=>{
  //acá resolvé lo que necesites.
});
```